# MariaDB insert with strange results

Tags: java, mysql, sql

We currently have MariaDB setup version 5.5.38 on Fedora.

When we run the following statement using Java:

```
INSERT INTO swiped.Users (userid, password, deviceToken) VALUES( ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE devicetoken = ?
```

We would expect it to either INSERT if the row doesn't already exist for the given key or UPDATE the existing one.

The UPDATE works fine but if we run this for a key that does not exist (say adsfadfafd4543545qefakdsf for example) in our database we get a random ID inserted. For example:

```
ID = 339
```

First of all there are only two rows in our database so there's no way ID should get a value of 339.

Comment: The other values look like base64, checked that? EDIT: Checked, valid base64 but contains just random binary data.

Comment: Probably the counter raises on every insert try, which IMO is good because the seed should be increased atomically per insert operation regardless of the result of the execution.

Comment: The explanation of @LuiggiMendoza is the right one. Have a look at SHOW CREATE TABLE Users too. It reports the value of the auto_increment. Do some inserts with an duplicate key and have another one at the current auto_increment value.